# Runtime error C0000005 of an unpacked executable file [UPX 3.91+]

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, ollydbg, x64dbg

The problem manifests itself when trying to execute an unpacked executable file. The original file is packaged with **UPX (3.91 +) [modified]**, which is reported by *Detect It Easy*.

---

The unpacking process looked like this:

- Using *x64dbg* the instructions were found:

```
lea rax, qword ptr ss: [rsp-80]
push 0
cmp rsp, rax
jne ***. 7FF7181DAD39
sub rsp, FFFFFFFFFFFFFF80
jmp ***. 7FF71816CE3C
```

- A valid entry point was defined by `jmp` data: `***.7FF71816CE3C`
- Using the *Scylla* module, with an indication of the true entry point, a dump and a fix of the dump were made.

> Note: there were 2 undefined imports when dumping, but I ignored them by deleting [image: (image)]

After running the fixed dump, an error occurred:

```
EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO:
           dwFirstChance: 1
           ExceptionCode: C0000005 (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
          ExceptionFlags: 00000000
        ExceptionAddress: 00007FFF02E2C286 <ntdll>
        NumberParameters: 2
ExceptionInformation [00]: 0000000000000000 Read
ExceptionInformation [01]: 00007FF71818F2C0 Inaccessible Address
First attempt at exception at 00007FFF02E2C286 (C0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)!
```

I would also like to note that the original application did not want to fully work under the *x64dbg* debug, just as it completed its work when it was attached to the process.

Sorry for the mistakes, I am still quite new and have only been doing this for the last 2 days. Thank you for your attention!

> I think that the source file is protected from this, which is probably obvious, but I do not know what to do at all, and the desire to achieve the goal does not disappear.

---

Execution environment:

```
OS Name:                   Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.19042 N/A Build 19042
System Type:               x64-based PC
```

Comment: this exception only say about that unpacked image is bad/wrong. nothing unusual in *not want to fully work under the debugger* - exist different ways for detect debugger attached and stop work after this. nothing more possible say based on current info. and question in what ?